# Background image of Winform Application is loading in parts

Tags: .net, winforms, background-image

I have a Winform page with size of `1193, 637`.On this form i have added one datepicker and around 10 others controls like Gridview ,Labels Textboxes and Checkboxes.Now i have added an image of same dimension as of my Winform and with size of `733Kb` as background image of my winform.Now when i am launching (Running) my application it is getting rendered (loaded) in part by part which is giving very bad user experience and i am not bale to find out why this is happening..

Please guide me to load my winform smoothly.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code that i have added in my constructor..

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```

but it is also not solving the issue..Please help..

Comment: Please show the code for how you are loading/setting this image

Comment: @JWiley I have added the code that i have added in my form's constructor but this is also not solving the issue..Please help.